# Getting nil while trying to create delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Bellow is my code. I am constantly getting error of unwrapping nil value while pushed one of these buttons. Why it happens?

ContainerViewController:

```
    protocol ButtonTitleSenderProtocol: class {
            func leftButtonTitle(title:String)
            func rightButtonTitle(title:String) 
    }   

    class ContainerViewController: UIViewController { [...]
            weak var delegate: ButtonTitleSenderProtocol?

            @IBAction func leftButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
                let myTitle = myLeftButtonOutlet.currentTitle!
                delegate!.leftButtonTitle(myTitle)
            }

            @IBAction func rightButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
                let myTitle = myRightButtonOutlet.currentTitle!
                delegate!.rightButtonTitle(myTitle)
            } 
    }
```

MyChatViewController:

```
    class MyChatViewController: ChatViewController, ButtonTitleSenderProtocol{ 
    [...]
            override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
                let myVC = ContainerViewController()
                myVC.delegate = self
            }

            func leftButtonTitle(title: String) {
                addNewMessage(title)
            }

            func rightButtonTitle(title: String) {
                addNewMessage(title)
            }   
    }
```

Comment: Because you force unwrap! **Dont do it**. Either the `currentTitle` is `nil` or the `delegate` is. Debug your code to see where you have to conditionally unwrap.

Comment: In `prepareForSegue(segue:sender:)` your a creating a whole new `ContainerViewController` object, is that normal? You don't use `segue.destinationViewController`?

Comment: You can't create any `UIViewController` with the default initializer `()`. You need the reference to the **real** object, initialized with the designated initializer, from the segue or with an outlet in Interface Builder.

Comment: @luk2302 Force unwrapping is exceptionally not the reason in this case. ;-)

Comment: @vadian I did realize that after seeing the answers, but it *might* actually be a follow-up issue as soon as the first one gets resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create object of `ContainerViewController's` object via `segue.destinationViewController`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let myVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ContainerViewController
    myVC.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This , There is problem in Your prepareForSegue . You are actually creating a new Instance and Assigning delegate to that instance instead of that one which is actually called

MyChatViewController:

```
    class MyChatViewController: ChatViewController, ButtonTitleSenderProtocol{ 
    [...]
            override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

                 if   let myVC = segue.destinationViewController as?ContainerViewController
              { 

            myVC.delegate = self


           }



            }

            func leftButtonTitle(title: String) {
                addNewMessage(title)
            }

            func rightButtonTitle(title: String) {
                addNewMessage(title)
            }   
    }
```